# FUSE for root filesystem in Linux?

Tags: linux, filesystems, fuse, initrd

Is it even possible to use a FUSE (non-networked) filesystem as root in Linux? I assume the program has to be present in the initrd, but I'm not sure about specifics. For instance does the FUSE program also have to be present in the same location on the main root, or does it only have to be present in initrd?

Answer (score 1):

Since I was just researching this topic: https://systemd.io/ROOT_STORAGE_DAEMONS/

So it's possible.

FUSE program would be your storage daemon and only needs to be present inside initrd.